# How can I draw part of a circle border in Android?

Tags: android, 2d

How can I draw this circle with only 1/8 of its border with another color in android?

[image]

Comment: question states 1/4; image shows approx. 1/8 If you can't get that right, writing the code is going to be difficult....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image looks a lot like a ProgressBar with the circular style. You might want to look at the ProgressBar class.

In [canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html), you can could draw the circle with the following steps

1. Draw an outer pink circle with drawCircle
2. Draw a grey arc with drawArc
3. Draw an inner circle with drawCircle, using the background color

Comment: SweepGradient would be easier. Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428477/androidcircle-with-sweepgradient-to-animate